# Is the google docs embeddable previewer out of beta and will it have an have an API?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-docs

https://docs.google.com/viewer is awesome, but there are some customizations I need to make, and documentation would be helpful. Discovered here http://googlesystem.blogspot.com... . Haven't seen any public documentation that would help.

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html covers the Google docs - where the above is more a clone of the Google Books  previewer http://books.google.com/books .

Answer (score 1):

Google docs viewer has been [embeddable for some time](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html). There are instructions [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer).

You can embed PDFs, PPTs, TIFFs, and even some DOCs in an `iFrame` by simply adding the parameter `&embedded=true` to the URL of a typical viewer page. So, to embed a pdf at `http://example.com/file.pdf`, you could use the following code:

```
<iframe
src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/file.pdf&embedded=true"
style="width:500px; height:500px;"
frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

(Formatted this way to show as much of the URL as possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are two unresolved issues with embedding Google Docs Viewer.  The first is a cookies issue with IE (not sure which versions but it's not just 6) that requires the user to change a setting and the fact that it shows a login page for users with expired google accounts sessions.

[Google Docs viewer in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792665/google-docs-viewer-in-ie)
[Embedded Google Docs PDF viewer displays login page rather than PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882999/embedded-google-docs-pdf-viewer-displays-login-page-rather-than-pdf)

These appear to be unresolved and cause problems for any serious use of docs viewer in an end-user facing application.