# Embedded Google Docs PDF viewer displays login page rather than PDF

Tags: google-docs

I have a Web page in which I embed a Google docs viewer in an iFrame

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=URL-encoded-URL&embedded=true" width="750" height="960" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

(where URL-encoded-URL is an actual encoded URL).

For many/most of my users, the Google PDF Doc viewer appears and displays the referenced PDF.

But some of my users instead see the Google Docs page with the login box. I've no idea why that happens. Has anyone heard of this happening? And more important, know why, and what can be done to ensure the PDF is shown.

Comment: Could it be a difference on webbrowser settings?

Comment: Seem to affect people who have gmail accounts. Have not been able to ascertain if this is every case, but is an emerging pattern...

Comment: What kind of url do you use in URL-encoded-URL. I can't seem to get the viewer to work with google authentication on non public files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I second Zhami's comment on the question. This happens when you (the user) has a google account whose login has expired. The login page shows them Email: field already filled in with your email but asks for your password. If you then click on "change user", the email field goes back to empty and then you can go back to the iframe page and you will see the document.

I think maybe we can say this is a google bug?

Comment: Is there an appropriate mailing list to which we can post this as a potential Google bug?

Comment: This seems to only be a problem in firefox.